# plt.bar bars are too far left, how to fix?

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

In `help(plt.bar)` of matplotlib version 2.0.0, it says that the bars are

```
[...] with rectangles bounded by:

  `left`, `left` + `width`, `bottom`, `bottom` + `height`
        (left, right, bottom and top edges)
```

Yet, calling `plt.bar(0, 1)` produces

[image]

which does not start at `left == 0`, but instead at `left - width/2 == -0.4`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer:

```
plt.bar(0, 1, align="center")
```

---

#### Why:

The [documentation on github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L1884) says to use `align=edge`:

The default is now

```
(x - width/2, x + width/2, bottom, bottom + height)
```

> [...] The *align* keyword-only argument controls if *x* is interpreted
>   as the center or the left edge of the rectangle.[...]

```
align : {'center', 'edge'}, optional, default: 'center'
    If 'center', interpret the *x* argument as the coordinates
    of the centers of the bars.  If 'edge', aligns bars by
    their left edges
    To align the bars on the right edge pass a negative
    *width* and ``align='edge'``
```